# `django.db.models.Model` replaced `django.db.models.base.Model`

Tags: django

When I configue a model:

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about.""""
    text = models.charField(max_length=200)
    data_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The path of class `Model` is `django.db.models.Model`

However,it's true path is `django.db.models.base.Model` from module `django/django/db/models/base.py` 
[django/base.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py)

The `base` level is jumped.

How Django achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look inside [`django/db/models/__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/__init__.py) - it has this line:

```
from django.db.models.base import DEFERRED, Model
```

Which is why you can import `Model` from `django.db.models`.

Python's [documentation on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) explains more about `__init__.py` usage.